# kivy - textinput from kv to py - import data

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to get the data from a simple textinput that is in my kv file and use the information in my python file.
but i keep getting the same error.
this error happens when i press a button and the function try to run looks like its trying to get the information from the text_location widget 
thank you in advance.

```
class ScatterTextWidget(BoxLayout):


    def initialize_request(self):
         ''' Initial analysis and control flow of the class '''

         location = self.ids.input_location
         date = S.ids.input_date
         time_raw = ScatterTextWidget.ids.input_time
         print(f'{location} - {date} - {time_raw}')

class HistoricalApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return ScatterTextWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    HistoricalApp().run()
```

the kivy file called "historical.kv"
i reduce it because is kind of long

```
<ScatterTextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#01183f')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
        valign: 'middle'

        TextInput:
            id:text_location
            width: 200
            id: input2
            font_size: 15
            size_hint_y: None
            height:40
        TextInput:
            id:input_date
            width: 200
            id: input1
            font_size: 15
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
        TextInput:
            id:input_time
            width: 200
            id: input1
            font_size: 15
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
```

the error i receive is

```
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 838, in 
 kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'text_location'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/IBKCo/Desktop/Git Programs/TimeStationHistoricalRecords/MainGui.py", line 77, in <module>
     HistoricalApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 340, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 325, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 291, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\pdEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\IBKCo\Desktop\Git Programs\TimeStationHistoricalRecords\historical.kv", line 127, in <module>
     on_release: root.initialize_request()
   File "C:/Users/IBKCo/Desktop/Git Programs/TimeStationHistoricalRecords/MainGui.py", line 31, in initialize_request
     location = self.ids.text_location
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

thank you in advance 
best,

Comment: You have several `ids` defined for each `TextInput`. Only the last will be in effect. And you have duplicate `ids`, not allowed.

Comment: wow i cant believe i didn't see that. that why sometimes you need a second couple of eyes to help you. thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to remove both of the `id:input1` lines and the `id:input2` line. Then change your `initialize_request` method to:

```
def initialize_request(self):
     ''' Initial analysis and control flow of the class '''

     location = self.ids.text_location.text
     date = self.ids.input_date.text
     time_raw = self.ids.input_time.text
     print(f'{location} - {date} - {time_raw}')
```

Note that `self.ids.text_location` is a reference to the `TextInput` widget, so you have to add `.text` to get its text. Same for the other `TextInput` widgets.

Comment: this is totally a rookie mistake. thank you to point it out, best,